# Insert into document library from another program

Tags: document-library

I have an in-house program I'm writing that needs to keep track and manage files.
We also have Sharepoint, where we have several document libraries.

I was going to use a [FileTable BLOB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server) to store the files, but then I started wondering if it might be possible to store them in Sharepoint to make accessing them a little easier, so long as I can also store their location in my SQL server table.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the SharePoint web services for such integrations.

Another option is to install client sdk and then use Client Object Model.